# Managing Multiple JVM

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I have some untrusted client code and I want to run it by initiating a java virtual machine instance for each client to manage the max memory used by the JVM for each instance and max running time the code is allowed to execute.
How can I do this ? 
Is there a code sample for such a thing ? 
I read about JVM pooling [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14032/jvm005.htm) and [there](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/oracle/B14099_16/web.1012/b14032/jvm.htm) but I couldn't understand how to do this ? 
I want to see some code

Comment: As I am sure you know, you can use the -XMX jvm parameter to cap the memory a given JVM can use. To launch each program in a different JVM, you would just a script on your server doing the launching with the given XMX. Beyond this, what part are you looking for sample code on?

Comment: I want to have multiple JVMs running, get their status info in a certain time (if finished) and if manage their standard I/O through the initiating JVM

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I participated in a [programming contest](http://www.hacker.org/worm/) where an algorithm had to fight against other algorithms. The site used a [special JVM](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~sabry/ojvm/) to limit the number of instructions you were allowed to use for your calculations in each step.

I think this is not exactly what you are looking for, because the java programs are highly restricted in the classes they can use. But since there are no other answers till now, this could be a starting point.